# Migrating Varchar to Text in Mysql

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I am converting one of the "Varchar" column in mysql table to a text field. I am simply using single alter command to convert the type. When i read about text and varchar came to know that it had difference in storing mechanisms.

Am I supposed to write any migration script to change the type of column and move data or a single type altering command is enough ?

Comment: if the alter survives, you are good to go

Comment: If I am going to do it in a Production setup ?

Comment: It is a very broad question or comment then. Some of the answers are on other rdbms' ... http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27153 ... so your question has been asked in many ways many times. Just look around at the prior write-ups

Answer (score 49):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name TEXT NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 14):

There is no a big problem to change `varchar` to `text` because `text` supports more data length than `varchar`, but if the field has a index it must be drop and create new index with prefix `col_name(length)` (see [CREATE INDEX syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html)).

According to your data content maybe would be a good idea use `fulltext` indexes but that implies change your search expressions on that field.

If you are in production environment, the table will be locked meanwhile the migration is in progress to prevent data loss.